# Any ideas why the Inherit is not available on a SPWeb?

Tags: master-page, spweb, custom-masterpage

Any ideas why the Inherit is not available on a SPWeb?

[image]

Comment: Are you on a subsite or a site collection?

Comment: This is a subsite (SPWeb)

ex: 
http://sp (SPSite)
http://sp/hr (SPWeb) - Somehow changing the master page setting here changes the http://sp master page settings. I need to stop this from happening.

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling the publishing feature on the sub-site?

Comment: Jesus Shelby, that was the solution. Thank You. 
PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin>Disable-spfeature Publishing -url http://yoursite/subsite -force

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> Enable-spfeature Publishing -url http://yoursite/subsite -force